# UI load issue with async await in Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, async-await

I am working on a Windows 8 app. In the ViewModel, I have a function called Initialize which loads the UI elements such as Comboboxes and GridViews. During development, I was using hardcoded values.

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        LoadLocations();
        List<string> filterNames = new List<string> { "Test", "Test1" };
        LoadMyFilters(filterNames);
        LoadPeople();
    }
```

I changed the code so that the filterNames are being loaded from the local file system as shown. I have introduced the async/await pattern.

```
    public async void Initialize()
    {
        LoadLocations();
        List<string> filterNames = await FileManager.Instance.GetMyFiltersNamesAsync();
        LoadMyFilters(filterNames);
        LoadPeople();
    }
```

Here is where I get confused. Once I introduced the asnyc await, UI does not load Filters and People. Filters and People are Observable Collections that are bound to the UI. I did verify that the code is being executed. GetMyFiltersNamesAsync just uses the built in .NET calls to connect to the local storage.

I checked the threads and noticed that the code is being run on a Worker thread and that was always the case. But I went ahead and used a dispatcher to run that just to ensure that the issue is not because the UI thread is not running the code. It still didnt load.

What is causing this issue and how can I fix this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sounds like await `FileManager.Instance.GetMyFilterNamesAsync()` is throwing an exception and you're not seeing it bubble up because Initialize is `async void` instead of `public Task InitializeAsync()`

Comment: I did verify that GetMyFilterNamesAsync() is returning the list and also the code that loads the ObservableCollection is being executed.

Comment: Where do you call `Initialize`?

Comment: I call it in the OnNavigatedTo event in the code behind of the Xaml file.

Comment: I think the RaisePropertyChanged call for the ObservableCollections is not causing the UI to reload.

Comment: Okay I explicitly called RaisePropertyChanged within each LoadMyFilters and LoadPeople and its loading now. I am not sure how it was loading before I introduced the async/await. Anyway...thanks everybody for your input. It helped me debug more to find the issue :)